# Search query in large multi-tenant database

Tags: performance, database-design, full-text-search

I have a fairly large table (700k rows) containing the main object of my application. This is a multi-tenant app. Typically, users have access to 1k rows of this table, but there are edge-cases with some users having access to all rows, and other users having access to maybe 100k rows.

We have a powerful/complex access right management system, so unfortunately there is no easy discriminator that would allow to compute accesses more efficiently than on a per-user basis.

The app has a search box which should allow users to quickly retrieve the first page of rows that match their query, sorted by relevance.

The normalized approach to this requirement is to have 2 tables, `data(id, content)` and `accesses(id, user_id)` and a query similar to :

```
select data.*
from data
join accesses using (id)
where accesses.user_id = :user_id
order by word_similarity(data.content, :search_term)
limit 50
```

We followed this approach. Our `data` table has 700k rows, `accesses` table has 58m rows. The performance of the search is not great.

It seems to me that our setup is classic, but I haven't found much resource on the web. For example, on google drive, users can grant access to each document to different users, and yet the search feature is very quick.

What is the usual approach to speed up search queries in large multi-tenant databases ?